# How To Initialize DropZone.js To Get It Working Properly?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

My HTML:

```
<form action="" class="dropzone">
    <div id="pck_Dropzone" class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

My JS:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(function(){
    var dropZone = new Dropzone("div#pck_Dropzone", {
        url: '/api/admin/UploadPackageImage',
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drag & Drop Images",
        clickable: true,
        enqueueForUpload: true,
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        maxFiles: 100,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        thumbnailWidth: 240,
        thumbnailHeight: 240,
        init: function(){
            console.log('init');
        }
    });
});
```

I know for a fact dropzone is attached to my DOM element. But its behavior doesn't come close to what's demo'ed and described in the documentation.

1. Other than the init function, no other event ever fires. I tried console logging the 'addedfile' event, according to the documentation. It does not work.
2. When I add multiple files and I call the getQueuedFiles() function, nothing is returned.
3. No image preview files are ever generated. No remove links are ever shown.
4. Dragging & dropping does not work. A drag & dropped image simply replaces the page the browser is currently showing (default browser behavior).
5. The dictDefaultMessage 'Drag & Drop Images' isn't shown. That one only shows if I init the form instead of the div.

I'm using the 5.5.1 version from cloudflare cdn. It's identical to the latest version from github.

Stack Overflow is rife with examples on how to use this plugin. I tried many code examples. It all fails to do anything.

[My dropzone looks like this.](http://prntscr.com/pavrqa)

No previews. No queue. No button to start uploading. No nothing.

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was placing it inside of a VueJS app. When placed outside of it, it worked right away.